# Worklight 6.1 and WP8: "Failed to load messages for all options.Files are missing in the path"

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

In the file www/default/worklight/worklight.js -> `function loadWLClientMessages(url,isLocal){...}` the messages.json is loaded.
After configuring a new wp8 project I got the error "Failed to load messages for all options.Files are missing in the path"

This could be fixed by adding at the beginning of the function loadWLClientMessages `url = "/www/default/" + url;`.
Does anybody know how I can overwrite the common worklight.js with a custom one? I tried already to put it to the Folder nativeRessources, but it did not worked.

Comment: Just to better understand what you're doing... You are trying to add localization support to your application in Windows Phone 8? Can you not use the messages.js file? That is, did you review the Enable Translation training module? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced-client-side-development

Comment: Hi, no, the app is not using any localization, it's out of the box in just a single language. This was not an issue on any other platform, just on Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

worklight.js is a framework file and you cannot override it.

Have you taken a look at the following IBM Worklight user documentation resources?

- [Enabling Translation training module](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced-client-side-development)
- [Developing globalized hybrid applications](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_developing_globalized_hybrid_apps.html)

You could use Cordova Globalization API, or jQuery Mobile's Globalization approach as well as use custom strings using messages.js (this is all explained in the second link above).

Because Windows Phone 8 and jQuery/jQuery Mobile do not play nice together when it comes to a multi-page application approach, I would suggest try the above options, instead of hacking inside the Worklight framework, which may lead to more headache than anything else.

You can also **edit the question** and better explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Idan, as I said above I don't try to do any localization. I create a brand new project ("Hello world") and the Windows8 phone gives me this error message....